# How to print the first ten results of the code

Tags: python, indexing, nltk, slice

How could I print only the first 10 results of my program? I tried creating an empty list but could not store the results properly to then print them.

```
    from nltk.corpus import brown

user_input = input('Input a sequence: ') #ADJ+NOUN+NOUN
User_Input = user_input.split('+')

words = brown.tagged_words(tagset='universal') #to access the POS tags

for i, word in enumerate(words):
    if i+2 < len(words):
        if words[i][1] == User_Input[0] and words[i+1][1] == User_Input[1] and words[i+2][1] == User_Input[2]:
            print(words[i], words[i+1], words[i+2])
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please use the available formatting options.

Comment: Please put code quotes around your code, put your question in the question body with some explanation, and come up with a short descriptive title instead of having the entire body text in the title.

Answer (score 0):

there a number of way to do it:

if the object containing the data already support slice notation, such as a list, you can simple do `data[:n]` were n is the number of items you want

```
>>> data=list(range(0,10**6,10))
>>> len(data)
100000
>>> data[:10] 
[0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90]
>>>
```

In a list case you get a new list with that many elements

If the object doesn't support slice notation or you don't want to use extra space on it in the case of a list, you can use the islice from the itertools module

```
>>> import itertools
>>> for n in itertools.islice(data,10):
        print("item",n)

    
item 0
item 10
item 20
item 30
item 40
item 50
item 60
item 70
item 80
item 90
>>>
```

other option is break the iteration when a the condition is met

```
>>> for i,n in enumerate(data):
        print("item",n)
        if i>=9:
            break

    
item 0
item 10
item 20
item 30
item 40
item 50
item 60
item 70
item 80
item 90
>>>
```